# CakePHP 3 Find threaded from id

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-3.0, children

Unfortunately I have a problem using CakePHP 3, again.

I have an entity called *Element* which implements the TreeBehavior and so contains a *parent_id*, a *lft* and a *rght* field.

What I'm trying to do very unsuccessfully right now is getting a subtree from any element as parent and displaying it with the TreeHelper from dereuromark.

If I use the usual way of retrieving threaded data `$this->Elements->find('threaded')` then `<?= $this->Tree->generate($a, ['model' => 'Element']); ?>` works perfectly and displays a beautiful tree of all my *Elements*.

Now I tried to get the children from one *Element* with id *43* via 
`$this->Elements->find('children', ['for' => 43])->find('threaded')`, as it is recommended in the [Red Velvet Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html#a-quick-tour), but a debug just gives me an empty array and the `Tree->generate` also doesn't work, obviously. Also, this would only give me an array of the children and not the *Element* with id *43* plus its nested children, correct? I think this is not what I need for the `Tree->generate`, though I don't understand why the code above is not working.

I also tried to use *Hash* but couldn't be successful with the TreeHelper, too.

Isn't there any simple method of getting the data I need and displaying it nicely? I would be glad for any helpful answers. Thank you!

Comment: Chaining `children` and `threaded` works fine for me. An empty array would indicate that there are no children for the node with the given ID. How can your problem be reproduced? ps, you should be able to include the parent node by simply adding an `orWhere()` with conditions for the ID.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick reply. Actually the query worked with a different entity, so I guessed that the lft and rght values could have been broken and added a `$this->Elements->recover();` before it and tried again. Now it is working and with the `orWhere()` I get my result as expected :)

Can you explain the way lft and rght work and when is the *recover* used normally? I think it cannot be a good idea to use it before every query.

Comment: Okay, I know where the problem is:

I have two Entities, one *Element* and one *CatalogElement*. There is bunch of *CatalogElements* existing in their table and what I'm trying to do is to copy some sub-tree out of the *CatalogElements*-table to the *Elements*-table. For that I created a function `cloneCatalogElement` that gets some *CatalogElement*, creates a new *Element*, recursively calls itself for all children of the *CatalogElement* (setting the new *Element*'s id as *parent_id*) and afterwards copies all required fields.

Can i do any better to make sure lft and rght are correct?